# Do Node.js-hosted files have their code exposed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I apologize for what might seem like a really dumb question based on a limited of Node.js but please know I am attempting to learn all I can. That being said, as I understand it, Node.js is similar to Apache or IIS. What types of files does it actually serve though (ASP, ASP.NET, PHP, HTML, etc.)?

My IMPRESSION is that it serves JavaScript and HTML by recommendation? In such a case, if I write a JavaScript file used on the server side to write data to my database, is my code exposed to the end user?

My scenario for example is that I would write an HTML5 page with JavaScript to write to a database but if that is served by Apache or IIS then both the HTML and JavaScript have their code exposed. How does this work with Node.js, do I need to stay with PHP for securing my code?

Thank you!

Comment: Javascript is a general purpose language just like any other, and Node is (more or less) just a framework for the language, like the standard library in C++. Unless you have configured the server wrong, the only data being sent is the data the application sends.

Comment: nodeJS is used in pretty much the same manner as PHP and any other language on the server-side, it's a backend that generates front end. Backend code isn't exposed unless the server is misconfigured - so just set it up correctly and you are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the server-side javascript isn't served to the requesting user you're safe. So no, the database stuff within nodejs won't be served.

That's like asking if PHPs or javas database code get served if someone requests a page (only if the code is read and echoed).

Comment: Interesting. So, if I wrote a PHP web service and uploaded it to a shared-hosting plan at GoDaddy I know the code that has the DB connection info is not visible to a client. If I write a JavaScript file to access the DB and upload that to the FTP then it sends that code to the user. Is this just because GoDaddy has no method for setting up "server side JavaScript" versus "client side JavaScript?"

Comment: Kind of. The difference is that you normally upload a javascript file to the web-root or document root (where you can access files by www) and when you're deploing nodejs apps there's some files, hidden from the world, that get interpreted and executed by nodejs (v8 engine, same as chrome uses).

Answer (score -1):

Node.js is a server-side scripting language with modules for interacting with HTTP requests and responses.

**You can serve literally any kind of file** with Node (as you could with other server-side scripting languages), and in fact, probably want to go out of your way not to let people grab any files they want.

**PHP won't secure your code for you**. Normally, nginx or Apache helps to protect against threats, but a Node.js server running on a port *completely bypasses all of that* unless you *specifically configure nginx or Apache to forward requests* to the port your node program is listening on.

Comment: Node.js itself is not a scripting langue. Node.js is comparable to what _Zend Engine_  is for php. Node.js is the interpreter/runtime environment for JavaScript. And Nginx/Apache doesn't do much for security if it is about dynamic webpages.